# How to solve "Driver class 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver' not found" on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, hive, database-connection

I am very new to IntelliJ, JDBC and hive. I have just mentioned the host name in data sources and drivers in apache hive, and when I click test connection, it says "Driver class 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver' not found". I haven't added any jar files and it says download missing file. But due to some error I cant download it automatically. I downloaded the hive-jdbc-3.1.2-standalone.jar but don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this driver and provide it as suggested.

Check that Intellij documentation with screenshots to configure a datasource :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-database-connections.html